# "Outbound namespace does not match any of the given schemas", when sending extracted XML message

Tags: xml, namespaces, maps, schema, biztalk

My scenario is like this:

I am receiving an XML from a database using the WCF-SQL adapter. On my receive location I am using an XML receive pipeline with the associated schema. On the receive port I have an inbound map, which simply outputs an XML message which is included in one of the XML elements of the incmong message. This XML message does not have a schema associated with it, but contains some namespaces.

My map simply does the following:

```
<xsl:template match="/NewTable">
        <xsl:value-of select="msgbody/text()" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
```

The error is referencing one of these namespaces on the outgoing document. I could provide a schema, but different messages can occur in the XML message (msgbody) received with different namespaces.

Question:

How can I make Biztalk ignore the namespace of the outgoing document, since it is not possible for me to provide a schema for it? The XML receive pipeline will in the future be switched to a custom made one, which routes the message in an external system.

Comment: have you tried your send port to use passthrough? what's the output?

Comment: Maps have to have associated Schemas.  Why can't you create Schemas?

Comment: I can't create a schema, because the structure of the XML message inside the receiving XML is unknown. No schema validation will need to take place, the message should be sent as passthrough after it has been extracted. I am also not using any send ports, since the message is being routed into an external system from the receive location. In that system however, the message is being sent as passthrough.

Comment: Unknown as in "can change randomly"?  Or will the root at least be consistent?

Comment: Not even the root can be expected to be consistent. The documents are being pulled from a central database containing all kinds of documents.